# Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' PHP and cPanel

Tags: php

I am trying to dynamically create Subdomains from my website CMS.

I have created the following script:
require_once "/usr/local/cpanel/php/cpanel.php";

```
$cpanel = new CPANEL();

$get_userdata = $cpanel->uapi(
    'DomainInfo', 'domains_data',
    array(
        'format' => 'hash',
    )
);

$addsubdomain = $cpanel->api2(
    'SubDomain', 'addsubdomain',
    array(
        'domain' => ''. $subdomain .'',
        'rootdomain' => 'REMOVED',
        'dir' => '/public_html/',
        'disallowdot' => '1',
    )
);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'There was a problem fetching the env variablecontaining the path to the socket' in /usr/local/cpanel/php/cpanel.php:146
```

Why is this and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when you're trying to use LiveAPI in PHP Script outside the cPanel's document root.

According to cPanel, LiveAPI can be used only from withing cPanel's document root: `/usr/local/cpanel/base/frontend/`, `/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/`.